# Lyx-:pdflatex - can't compile saved files but can compile copy pasting the entire article

Tags: pdftex, lyx

Hi guys I have a weird error.
it says
[image]

When I check the logs I cannot find any errors, rather a few warnings:

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Hebrew' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for \language=0 instead on input line 57.

Package babel Info: \l@hebrew = using hyphenrules for english
(babel)             (\language0) on input line 58.

The only document type I use is standard article and the packages are only babel.
This usually happens after I work on a project and then save it or reopen it.
If i copy the entire content of the article and paste it into a new lyx document-exactly the same, then it will compile.
I have had the exact same error with lyx 64 bit,32 bit, miktex 32 bit and miktex 64 bit, all combinations possible.
Any other solutions other than switching a latex environment?
Much apprieciated,Danny

Comment: If copy/paste works, then the problem is likely in the Document > Settings. When you copy/paste into a new document the new document settings a fresh/default. Look specifically at differences in the LaTeX preamble settings, the modules, the local layout, and the document class tab of document settings.

Comment: Odd, didn't see any difference
Could it be because I'm saving the .lyx file with a foreign language and not English?

Comment: Not sure, the best would be if you open the two files with something like "meld", which shows the differences. If you happen to be on Ubuntu, just do `sudo apt-get install meld` and then `meld file1.lyx file2.lyx`. That will give an idea of what the differences are in the .lyx files. Note that .lyx files are just text files so you can view them in a text editor or diff program to inspect them.